# Why are we using utf8mb4_general_ci and not utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: database

Drupal is moving to support utf8mb4, however, it is using utf8mb4_general_ci. Why take the time to move over to support it, and then not fully support it? Is there a specific reason, or just continuing utf8_general_ci from previous?

Would there be any problems with ignoring this and using Unicode anyway?

Drupal Ticket:
[MySQL driver does not support full UTF-8 (emojis, asian symbols, mathematical symbols)](https://www.drupal.org/node/1314214)

Here is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) on stack exchange which says really there is no reason not to use Unicode now days and finally, on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344118/utf-8-general-bin-unicode), it says "utf8_general_ci is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters."

I note that WordPress uses utf8mb4_unicode_ci.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me that the recommendation is outdated and that  `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` will work without problems. It has been used by a lot of people for a long time.

---

There is a difference between changing the character set from `utf8` to `utf8mb4` (to support more codepoints) and changing the collation from `general_ci` to `unicode_ci` (to get more accurate sorting). Both changes can cause their own problems, so doing both independently makes sense.

[`utf8mb4` is used by default since 8.0.0-beta12](https://www.drupal.org/node/2510940). The main issue seemed to be a change of key lengths limitations for InnoDB but as I understand it, `utf8mb4` should have worked with the default MyISAM engine even before that change.

Switching to `unicode_ci` shouldn't cause problems, but may unexpectedly changes the order of sorting for some sites.

The default collation setting is just a *default* and modules can choose their own collations anyway if they need to. I also haven't found any documentation that says modules should expect a certain collation. The [database install guide](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/create-database) just lacks a clear statement about which collations are supported and is inconsistent:

- In the section about phpMyAdmin it says that you have to

  > Make sure you select COLLATION utf8_general_ci
- Later in the section about installation from command line, `general_ci` doesn't seem to be required and any UTF-8 collation will do:

  > Note: The database should be created with UTF-8 (Unicode) encoding, for example utf8_general_ci.

Furthermore, PostgreSQL is supported and it seems its default UTF-8 collation is equivalent to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, so using that with MySQL should be fine too.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for helping me understand this!

Answer (score 2):

Below link explains that utf8mb4_unicode_ci is better than utf8mb4general_ci (which is a little bit faster) because the second one have problems in sorting order in some languages:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/860099